# How to run 100's of rules on Graph data?

Tags: neo4j, sparql, drools, graphdb

I have historical transactional data. The requirement is to evaluate all the conditions on the historical data for the new transaction (such as a new payment transaction)

For eg: The new Payment transaction will evaluate the following conditions:
 - If payment is  made by credit card
 - If there were multiple payment failures (considering historical data)
 - If the credit card in the payment is used by some other account.(considering historical data)

There are above 100 relationship based conditions that need to run on such historical data (spanning several years). Thus, I was assuming to use a Graph DB to store the tuples and then create a condition statement covering it all? But, I need to know also which condition held true. Thus, the only other option is to run the queries per condition which is a challenge for real-time use-cases.

Is there another alternative, performant approach to this?

Comment: You may want to consider an engine that's built for this sort of requirement, like my employer's [Virtuoso 8](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) with its Custom Reasoning & Inference Module (among other features).

Comment: It's not clear what rules means in this context? Are you sure you don't need constraints instead? I mean, rules are mostly for inference, constraints to validate data. SHACL would be a good constraint language for RDF data.

Comment: Regarding rules (if you really mean rules): There are multiple triple stores supporting rules, often in their own syntax, some do support SWRL to some extent. What I still don't get is what you mean by run SPARQL and then "know which rule returned true" - so, please show some rules in a more formal way.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, rename rules to conditions (makes sense). So let me rephrase my question? "I can create tuples from historical data, then query the tuples with all of the conditions". But, I need to know which condition has been satisfied. So, instead of running all conditions at the same time, I will need to run them individually. That is a concern for real-time use-cases with 100's of queries to run at the same time. I was thinking if there could be another approach?

Comment: I see that you tagget the question "Drools" are you already using it? But yet Drools might be a nice solution to your problem

Comment: I think, the right solution should be similar to this: 
1) Analyze & Prepare all the data required by graph queries periodically (every 15 mins) and send the result set to Drools Search Engine to decide what to do with each of them to return an array of actions. (Batch)
2) Analyze & Prepare all the data required by graph queries periodically (every 15 mins) and store the results in a DB for insights (numberOfPayments made per customer, etc) In addition, create Graph Structure in the memory using GraphScale and derive the required additional insights. then, send it all to Drools to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max De Marzi has written a post on [building rules engines](https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/08/25/building-a-boolean-logic-rules-engine-in-neo4j/) that you may find interesting:

He has also written a couple of posts on finding fraud based on linking [irregular purchase behaviours](https://maxdemarzi.com/2019/08/19/finding-fraud/#more-5140) together, along with [detecting fraud rings](https://maxdemarzi.com/2019/08/20/finding-fraud-part-two/#more-5190), which sounds similar to the theme you are looking to explore.